# EntityFrame Work does not recognize one-to-many association. why?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, database-design, entity-framework-4.1

### **EDIT**

> Please view the following image, it details the PICTURES which show
>   that only ADO.NET ENTITY FRAME WORK DOESNOT recognize one to many
>   association but the DATASET DOES.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzzhZ.jpg.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzzhZ.jpg)

(sorry but i do not have enough reputation to upload the image directly)

**I have two tables**

table1: Name
[NAMEID, NAME] (NAMEID is the PK)

table2: Description 
[DESCID,DESCRIPTION,IDofNAME](DESCID is the PK, and IDofNAME is the FK related to NAMEID)

one name can have many descriptions, which themselves are independent of the name.

The dataentry from SQL SERVER works, and the relationship is also preserved.

### but, PROBLEM

> In vs10 Data Sources the "Name" table has a child "Description" which
>   again has a child "Name" which again has a child "Description" and
>   this continues with no end.
>
> The same is for the "description" table relation with "name" table
>   which has child/relation with "description" table, which again has
>   relation with "name" table and this thing has no end.

### On grid Problem

The datagrid which is made on design time by drag-drop of the NAME table, displays fields
[nameid, name, NAME OF THE RELATED TABLE (not the fields the whole NAME!)

PLEASE HELP ME OUT HERE, what am i doing wrong in making the relation of pk-fk

thanku

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your tables might be in a many to many relationship.
One name can have many descriptions, each can describe zero or more names.
If this is the case you should add a resolver table between them eg

```
CREATE TABLE NameDescription
    ([nameid] [int] NOT NULL,
     [descriptionid] [int] NOT NULL )
```

With this approach you will no longer need the foreign key in the Description table and instead you will join through this new table.

Comment: This is not the case, the relationship is one-to-many. please see the edit, i have linked an image kindly please help. (sorry dont have enough rep to uplod theimage directly)